# Is there a browser plugin for taking screenshots of individual elements in a web page?

Tags: plugins, firebug, screenshot, element

I'm looking for a plugin that would allow you to select an individual element of a web page, (much like firebug) and save a screenshot of just that element. Does such a plugin exist for any browser?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, [Screengrab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/screengrab/) will [snapshot just the parts of a webpage you select](http://www.screengrab.org/home/features/selection/).

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/screengrab/ : Screengrab! saves webpages as images... but not for new versions of Firefox. FF changes too fast and I don't have the time to maintain it anymore. Bugs have developed that I am not in a position to investigate. Therefore, Screengrab is EOL.